How to enable JavaScript in the TWebBrowser component for Delphi 2006?
I have a simple application built in Delphi 2006 with a few components as follows:
procedure TForm1.cmdBackClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbrowser1.GoBack;
end;

procedure TForm1.cmdLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbrowser1.Navigate(txtAddress.text);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbrowser1.silent:= true;
end;

and when I navigate to this URL: https://smallseotools.com/what-is-my-browser/ in TWebBroweser then there is info about my browser version and also information:

Javascript is not enabled.

How can I enable JavaScript there?
I have tried setting up different IE versions via the registry keys:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

but it looks like it has no impact on Javascript enabling/disabling.
Now I have here value 2af9, so when I open the URL above it reports I have IE11 with JavaScript disabled.
Also. I am running Windows 10 Pro, 22H2, 19045.4046
How to enable JavaScript in the TWebBrowser component?

Did you create a new DWORD key with for example the name of your app "myapp.exe" under your registry path with decimal value 11001 (0x2af9 in hex)? If yes, then you need run your app from the exe files instead from IDE.
Also if you are controlling code of the webpage, you can try put meta: 

yes i did it exactly as you wrote (i created dword with name of exe and value 2af9 and run exe directly - not via ide).

Try setting webbrowser1.silent:= true; to false.  When I do that on Delphi 2007 it shows several javascript errors on the https://smallseotools.com/what-is-my-browser/ url, this would suggest that the javascript they are running on the site is not compatible with IE11. The silent propery will hide thease errors from you at runtime.

Looking at the error I get wien silent=false, it says its on Line 1, char 182 of the myscript.js file, that refers to the default paramater in the function setCookie(name,value,Exp_minutes,path="path=/"), Can I Use says default paramater values are a no go in IE 6..11 (https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_functions_default_parameters)

What Windows version does your computer have? It is possible that Microsoft intentionally broke the way how this IE compatibility mode works in order to force people and developers to move from WebView that IE used to newer WebView2 that Edge is using. So you might want to consider updating your application to longer rely on TWebBrowser but instead use CEF4Delphi which allows you to embed Chromium-based browsers in Delphi applications. Based on its website it can was tested even on ancient Delphi 6.

Hi I have Windows 10 Pro, 22H2, 19045.4046. I will try CEF4Delphi

The point of this post is i have used webbrowser  for displaying map in my application. Source of the map is webservice which i called by opening local html file created by me. It worked for years and recently it has stopped worked. File which i use for generating map has javascript inside and this is unfortunatelly blacbox for me so now im trying to understand what has changed. Is there somebody who can check my example file and give me advice whats wrong? Example of file in my next post. Works in MS Edge but has stopped work in my delphi app which uses webbrowser. ThankYouVeryMuch

<!doctype html>










